# My web page all of a sudden opens only partially and cannot be changed

Tags: windows, web, internet-explorer-9, windows-vista

Vista 32; IE9; FrontPage 2003. I've updated my web page for years on a daily basis. Today, after updating my web page only displayed less than half of the Home Page. All other pages of my web page worked. Other computers were able to open the web page normally.
I tried to change the Home Page and uploaded, but the result was the same. I refreshed the page, I restarted and new-started the computer,no difference. I've spent several hours trying to fix the problem myself, but to no avail.
Thanks for any help
Max Klepp

Comment: This is a computer problem and no programing problem.so i think this question wil be closed.If the page works on other computers then for sure the problem must be your computer.mybe becaus you use ie9.do you have a backup of youre webpage before the problem started?if so upload it and check if you stil have the problem.if not check what you changed on your page.mybe it dos not work on ie9.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I realized too late that I was in the wrong forum. You're right, it's of course not a programming problem. PLUS: today everything works without any changes having been made. There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,...
Thanks for all your efforts
Max Klepp